# Configuring VS Code for debugging Rust

Tags: visual-studio-code, rust, vscode-debugger

I have been through the official VS Code documentation section on Rust and I have the Rust Analyzer extension installed.

But I can't seem to see break points that I set in the code.

I see what appears to be assembler.

Is there another clear step by step guide to configuring VS Code to debug Rust programs?

I have been through the VS Code documentation on debugging Rust

I have installed the necessary extensions according to the documentation.

I can get a debug session to run.

Source code:

[image: Sample program]

Running debug:

[image: Running debug]

Comment: Can you show the steps you made, preferably with a small example project? And then what output you see?

Comment: Original question updated with screen shots of source code and what I see when I run debug

Comment: What does "throught" mean?

Comment: The sentence was meant to be, "I have been through" throught was a typo. UK English for thru.

Answer (score 0):

I tried setting a function breakpoint on `main`, and it does indeed show assembly. This is probably a limitation of lldb/rust/vscode, and not user error. If you set a breakpoint in the file, though, it does work:

[image: screenshot of VS Code stopped at a breakpoint on line 5 in main.rs]

If that workaround doesn't work for you, you'll probably be best [finding/opening an issue on the CodeLLDB repo](https://github.com/vadimcn/vscode-lldb/issues).